# RuntimeError: Exception encountered when calling LSTMGC.call(). Could not automatically infer the output shape / dtype of 'lstmgc_12' (of type LSTMGC)

Tags: python, neural-network, keras-3

I use the model from [this keras example](https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_traffic_forecasting/) based on GCN and LSTM. I trained the model and saved it using the `keras.saving.save_model()` method. In order to load it later, I implemented `get_config()` method for each of my custom object : `GraphInfo`, `GraphConv` and `LSTMGC` which looks like this respectively :

```
# GraphInfo 
def get_config(self):
        config = {
            'edges': self.edges,
            'num_nodes': self.num_nodes
        }
        return config
```

```
# GraphConv
def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update({
            "in_feat": self.in_feat,
            "out_feat": self.out_feat,
            "graph_info": self.graph_info.get_config(),
            "aggregation_type": self.aggregation_type,
            "combination_type": self.combination_type,
            "activation": self.activation.__name__ if self.activation else None,
        })
        return config
```

```
# LSTMGC
def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update({
            "in_feat": self.graph_conv.in_feat,
            "out_feat": self.graph_conv.out_feat,
            "lstm_units": self.lstm.units,
            "input_seq_len": self.input_seq_len,
            "output_seq_len": self.output_seq_len,
            "graph_info": self.graph_conv.graph_info.get_config(),
            "graph_conv_params": { 
                "aggregation_type": self.graph_conv.aggregation_type,
                "combination_type": self.graph_conv.combination_type,
                "activation": self.graph_conv.activation,
            }
            
        })
        return config
```

The prediction over the test set with the variable 'model' works fine, the saving too. However, when I try to load my trained my model to make predictions (to avoid the training phase each time), I got this error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[147], line 3
      1 #charger le modele
      2 path_to_save = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'saved_models'), 'model_test.keras')
      3 #custom_objects = {"GraphConv": GraphConv, "GraphInfo": GraphInfo, "LSTMGC": LSTMGC}
----> 4 loaded_model = keras.saving.load_model(path_to_save)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\statistiques\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\saving\saving_api.py:176, in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode)
    173         is_keras_zip = True
    175 if is_keras_zip:
--> 176     return saving_lib.load_model(
    177         filepath,
    178         custom_objects=custom_objects,
    179         compile=compile,
    180         safe_mode=safe_mode,
    181     )
    182 if str(filepath).endswith((".h5", ".hdf5")):
    183     return legacy_h5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\statistiques\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\saving\saving_lib.py:153, in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode)
    151 # Construct the model from the configuration file in the archive.
    152 with ObjectSharingScope():
--> 153     model = deserialize_keras_object(
    154         config_dict, custom_objects, safe_mode=safe_mode
    155     )
    157 all_filenames = zf.namelist()
    158 if _VARS_FNAME + ".h5" in all_filenames:

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\statistiques\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\saving\serialization_lib.py:707, in deserialize_keras_object(config, custom_objects, safe_mode, **kwargs)
    705 with custom_obj_scope, safe_mode_scope:
    706     try:
--> 707         instance = cls.from_config(inner_config)
    708     except TypeError as e:
    709         raise TypeError(
    710             f"{cls} could not be deserialized properly. Please"
    711             " ensure that components that are Python object"
   (...)
    715             f"\n\nconfig={config}.\n\nException encountered: {e}"
    716         )

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\statistiques\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\model.py:492, in Model.from_config(cls, config, custom_objects)
    487 if is_functional_config and revivable_as_functional:
    488     # Revive Functional model
    489     # (but not Functional subclasses with a custom __init__)
    490     from keras.src.models.functional import functional_from_config
--> 492     return functional_from_config(
    493         cls, config, custom_objects=custom_objects
    494     )
    496 # Either the model has a custom __init__, or the config
    497 # does not contain all the information necessary to
    498 # revive a Functional model. This happens when the user creates
   (...)
    501 # In this case, we fall back to provide all config into the
    502 # constructor of the class.
    503 try:

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\statistiques\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\functional.py:522, in functional_from_config(cls, config, custom_objects)
    520 node_data = node_data_list[node_index]
    521 try:
--> 522     process_node(layer, node_data)
    524 # If the node does not have all inbound layers
    525 # available, stop processing and continue later
    526 except IndexError:

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\statistiques\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\functional.py:469, in functional_from_config.<locals>.process_node(layer, node_data)
    466 args, kwargs = deserialize_node(node_data, created_layers)
    467 # Call layer on its inputs, thus creating the node
    468 # and building the layer if needed.
--> 469 layer(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\statistiques\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:123, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    120     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    121     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    122     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 123     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    124 finally:
    125     del filtered_tb

Cell In[137], line 45, in LSTMGC.call(self, inputs)
     42 # convert shape to  (num_nodes, batch_size, input_seq_len, in_feat)
     43 inputs = ops.transpose(inputs, [2, 0, 1, 3])
---> 45 gcn_out = self.graph_conv(
     46     inputs
     47 )  # gcn_out has shape: (num_nodes, batch_size, input_seq_len, out_feat)
     48 shape = ops.shape(gcn_out)
     49 num_nodes, batch_size, input_seq_len, out_feat = (
     50     shape[0],
     51     shape[1],
     52     shape[2],
     53     shape[3],
     54 )

Cell In[136], line 85, in GraphConv.call(self, features)
     76 """Forward pass.
     77 
     78 Args:
   (...)
     82     A tensor of shape `(num_nodes, batch_size, input_seq_len, out_feat)`
     83 """
     84 nodes_representation = self.compute_nodes_representation(features)
---> 85 aggregated_messages = self.compute_aggregated_messages(features)
     86 return self.update(nodes_representation, aggregated_messages)

Cell In[136], line 62, in GraphConv.compute_aggregated_messages(self, features)
     61 def compute_aggregated_messages(self, features):
---> 62     neighbour_representations = tf.gather(features, self.graph_info.edges[1])
     63     aggregated_messages = self.aggregate(neighbour_representations)
     64     return ops.matmul(aggregated_messages, self.weight)

RuntimeError: Exception encountered when calling LSTMGC.call().

Could not automatically infer the output shape / dtype of 'lstmgc_12' (of type LSTMGC). Either the `LSTMGC.call()` method is incorrect, or you need to implement the `LSTMGC.compute_output_spec() / compute_output_shape()` method. Error encountered:

Exception encountered when calling GraphConv.call().

'TrackedDict' object has no attribute 'edges'

Arguments received by GraphConv.call():
  • features=tf.Tensor(shape=(240, None, 12, 1), dtype=float32)

Arguments received by LSTMGC.call():
  • args=('<KerasTensor shape=(None, 12, 240, 1), dtype=float32, sparse=False, name=input_layer_12>',)
  • kwargs=<class 'inspect._empty'>
```

I tried to load the model with the `custom_objects` argument too, as it is written in my code but did not work. Finally, I don't know how to build the `compute_output_spec()` or `compute_output_shape()` methods that the error mentionned, if it is the good direction to point out.

Environment : windows 11, python 3.11, keras 3.0

Thank you for your help !